# (Python) eth_getFilterChanges --> data --> how to decode?

Tags: contract-development, python, pyethereum

Edit: solved, scroll down.

## How to decode filter results?

A contract is emitting this Event

```
event Send(address from, address to, uint value)
```

With `ethjsonrpc`  and its `eth_getFilterChanges` I am receiving this filterlog:

```
filterChanges=[{u'address': u'0x3673d5b436089c9aa3f59df5062c7431c86c21d7',
  u'blockHash': u'0x4bf30aba20336f634cfb638dab2bc72b06f79ae21072466102d3bde1247a016c',
  u'blockNumber': u'0xb5bed',
  u'data': u'0x000000000000000000000000157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f00000000000000000000000043bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002',
  u'logIndex': u'0x0',
  u'topics': [u'0x93eb3c629eb575edaf0252e4f9fc0c5ccada50496f8c1d32f0f93a65a8257eb5'],
  u'transactionHash': u'0x76b0bf4e5cdaee03725c97710ee3d3f218971664231c7e3259935d3d1b210443',
  u'transactionIndex': u'0x0'}]
```

Now I am trying to decipher that `'data'`-item which is clearly (address, address, amount).

But how to transform it with the python libraries?

```
data = filterChanges[0]["data"]
print data
print len(data)

import ethereum.abi
data_dec = ethereum.abi.decode_abi(["address", "address", "uint256"], data)
pprint (data_dec)
```

results in

```
0x000000000000000000000000157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f00000000000000000000000043bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
194
['3030303030303030303030303030313537666237',
 '3538333366313264393839376465383630306239',
  22343880564164347692490066462159793276992634768622606872680301975360839562809L]
```

Any hints?
Thx.

---

## Edit: Solved

the decode_abi function expects binary data

```
filterChanges=[{u'address': u'0x3673d5b436089c9aa3f59df5062c7431c86c21d7',
  u'blockHash': u'0xabbaaefe73c34ddfce9c3656ede6a754d105f1a2b43fbcf28baad633703d095c',
  u'blockNumber': u'0xb914d',
  u'data': u'0x00000000000000000000000043bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be1000000000000000000000000157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a',
  u'logIndex': u'0x0',
  u'topics': [u'0x93eb3c629eb575edaf0252e4f9fc0c5ccada50496f8c1d32f0f93a65a8257eb5'],
  u'transactionHash': u'0x89247c65380bf66a194a72b01a750356ee4cb8e3ce336dbaaba89b527c21de47',
  u'transactionIndex': u'0x0'}]

logdata_hex = filterChanges[0]["data"]
print; print logdata_hex; print len(logdata_hex)

logdata_hex_wo_0x =  logdata_hex[2:]
print; print logdata_hex_wo_0x; print len(logdata_hex_wo_0x)

logdata = logdata_hex_wo_0x.decode('hex')
print; print logdata; print len(logdata)

import ethereum.abi
data_dec = ethereum.abi.decode_abi(["address", "address", "uint256"], logdata)
print; pprint (data_dec)
```

### results in:

```
0x00000000000000000000000043bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be1000000000000000000000000157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a
194

00000000000000000000000043bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be1000000000000000000000000157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a
192

C�i�<@������=��{��V2W�pX3�-��ކ�*
96

['43bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be1',
 '157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f',
 42]
```

Thanks to @hack.augusto

---

tags: Python, contract-logs, pyethereum, ethjsonrpc, decode

Comment: You can answer your own question by posting your results below. This will help other users to faster spot the solution and vote up on helpful content. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved

the decode_abi function **expects binary data**

```
filterChanges=[{u'address': u'0x3673d5b436089c9aa3f59df5062c7431c86c21d7',
  u'blockHash': u'0xabbaaefe73c34ddfce9c3656ede6a754d105f1a2b43fbcf28baad633703d095c',
  u'blockNumber': u'0xb914d',
  u'data': u'0x00000000000000000000000043bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be1000000000000000000000000157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a',
  u'logIndex': u'0x0',
  u'topics': [u'0x93eb3c629eb575edaf0252e4f9fc0c5ccada50496f8c1d32f0f93a65a8257eb5'],
  u'transactionHash': u'0x89247c65380bf66a194a72b01a750356ee4cb8e3ce336dbaaba89b527c21de47',
  u'transactionIndex': u'0x0'}]

logdata_hex = filterChanges[0]["data"]
print; print logdata_hex; print len(logdata_hex)

logdata_hex_wo_0x =  logdata_hex[2:]
print; print logdata_hex_wo_0x; print len(logdata_hex_wo_0x)

logdata = logdata_hex_wo_0x.decode('hex')
print; print logdata; print len(logdata)

import ethereum.abi
data_dec = ethereum.abi.decode_abi(["address", "address", "uint256"], logdata)
print; pprint (data_dec)
```

### results in:

```
0x00000000000000000000000043bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be1000000000000000000000000157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a
194

00000000000000000000000043bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be1000000000000000000000000157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a
192

C�i�<@������=��{��V2W�pX3�-��ކ�*
96

['43bc6919fd3c40dce81fb4b00bd7e33db68b7be1',
 '157fb756013257b2705833f12d9897de8600b91f',
 42]
```

Thanks to @hack.augusto for the hint with the binary data.

Comment: posted here because [5chdn asked me to](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6297/python-eth-getfilterchanges-data-how-to-decode#comment5956_6297)

Comment: Thanks. You can also mark it as accepted by clicking the tick under the vote score.

Comment: Done. You are great!

Answer (score 3):

The JSONRPC returns the data field hex-encoded and the `decode_abi` function expects binary data, so you need to decoded the data field before calling `decode_abi`.

```
import ethereum.abi
logdata_hex = filterChanges[0]['data']
logdata = logdata_hex.decode('hex')
# the addresses will be hex-encoded
data = ethereum.abi.decode_abi(['address', 'address', 'uint256'], logdata)
```

Comment: almost. I had to remove the "0x" then it worked. I have edited my OP. Thanks a lot @hack.augusto