# Decode Etherscan.io Contract Input Data

Tags: web3js, etherscan, abi, calldata

Reading my input data on etherscan, I see each value as hex values. Which is fine to read the addresses. But I would like to read the amounts `[1]` && `[3]` as numbers.

### Contract Method

```
Function: trade(address tokenGet, uint256 amountGet, address tokenGive, uint256 amountGive, uint256 expires, uint256 nonce, address user, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint256 amount)
```

### input data

```
MethodID: 0x0a19b14a
[0]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[1]:000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016d8fceafcef3c0000
[2]:000000000000000000000000340d2bde5eb28c1eed91b2f790723e3b160613b7
[3]:00000000000000000000000000000000000000000008b7363b040ca2bb600000
```

I made a transaction etherdelta where I bought `25` tokens. So the expected transformed value of the input data `[1]` should be `25` or `25 * 10^18` (in wei) or at least any multiple of `25*10^x`.

### Question

How to convert the hex to the expected value?

### Tries

1. Using [ethereum input decoder](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder)
   shows me the same values as on etherscan.io
2. converting to Ascii gives garbage (as recommended here: [How to decode input data from a transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11144/how-to-decode-input-data-from-a-transaction))
3. `web3.utils.hexToNumberString` & `web3.utils.hexToNumber` err
4. `console.log(0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016d8fceafcef3c0000)`
   shows some arbitrary value

Comment: Do you have the transaction id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Miguel Mota page](https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/), using Etherdelta ABI, and your transaction input I get

```
{
  "name": "trade",
  "types": [ .. ],
  "inputs": [
    "0",
    "16d8fceafcef3c0000",      // <- amountGet
    "340d2bde5eb28c1eed91b2f790723e3b160613b7",
    "8b7363b040ca2bb600000",   // <- amountGive
    "46eeac",
    "87d84d79",
    "14ce500a86f1e3ace039571e657783e069643617",
    "1c",
    {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [..]
    },
    {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [..]
    },
    "38d7ea4c68000"            // <- amount
  ]
}
```

The commented values are those used to calculate what you receive. This is done in Ethedeleta `tradeBalances` function

```
  function tradeBalances(address tokenGet, uint amountGet, 
      address tokenGive, uint amountGive, 
      address user, uint amount) private {
    ...
    tokens[tokenGive][msg.sender] = 
       safeAdd(tokens[tokenGive][msg.sender], 
       safeMul(amountGive, amount) / amountGet);
  }
```

You should receive amountGive * amount / amountGet

> 0x8b7363b040ca2bb600000 * 0x38d7ea4c68000 / 0x16d8fceafcef3c0000
>   25000000000000000000L = 25*10^18

Which is what you expected.

Comment: Ok, the calculation is indeed correct. `amount` is actually the amount I spend `0.001 eth`.  `amountGive/amountGet ` is basically the price. I'm still puzzled what `amountGive ` and `amountGet`is. According to the [overview ](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/comments/6kdiyl/smart_contract_overview/) they should be the amount (in my case 25x10^18 & 4x10^10). 

> amountGet and amountGive represent the size and price you want to trade

Comment: I'm not an Etherdelta expert, but I'd guess they are the original offer amounts, you only buy less than the total to sell.