# How to access Mist transaction logs?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have a private blockchain deployed on one machine and Mist & Ethereum Wallet on another machine. Both the machines are connected through RPC. I have made a simple smart contract which adds two numbers.

I submit a transaction through Mist which gets sent to the blockchain.

Suppose, my inputs are 4 & 5, where are these inputs stored in the blockchain? Where is the output stored? Can I access these logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the machine, where your geth node is running, you can call `geth attach ipc:<PATH_TO_IPC_FILE>` to open the console of the node. The IPC file is usually located at `datadir/geth.ipc`.

Via the console you can fetch the transactions, transaction receipts and storage values using the web3 0.2x.x API (->https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).

Examples:

- `eth.getTransaction(<TRANSACTION_HASH>)`
- `eth.getTransactionReceipt(<TRANSACTION_HASH>)`
- `eth.getStorageAt(<CONTRACT_ADDR>, <POSITION>)`

However, all data is in the encoded form, so it will not be very readable. it can be decoded if you have the ABI (interface) of the contract. -> "[How to decode input data from a transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11144/how-to-decode-input-data-from-a-transaction)"