# web3.toAscii(transaction hash) for web3js version 1

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript

When i used `web3.toAscii` I received the following error :

[image]

I think the reason is my web3 version i.e. `'1.0.0-beta.34'`

If so, is there any alternative command for web3 version 1 for the following command ?

```
transaction = web3.eth.getTransaction('0x0c485e0f155f7f216d06e70ef85b684392c9b190c2f7c0af67ec1b56d6945498')
input = web3.toAscii(transaction.input)
console.log(input)
```

I also used following command :

```
web3.utils.hexToAscii(0x0c485e0f155f7f216d06e70ef85b684392c9b190c2f7c0af67ec1b56d6945498)
```

However, I receive the following error :

[image]

That mean its input cannot be a transaction hash.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent should be [web3.utils.hexToAscii](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii)

```
web3.utils.hexToAscii('0x4920686176652031303021');
> "I have 100!"
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this, however its input cannot be a transaction hash. I explained this in my question.

Comment: @sas You are missing `"` around your parameter `web3.utils.hexToAscii("0x0c485e0f155f7f216d06e70ef85b684392c9b190c2f7c0af67ec1b56d6945498")`. In any case it doesn't make much sense to use `hexToAscii` with a transaction hash or a `transaction.input`. It was intended to use on some fields that were generated by `asciiToHex` like `block.extraData`.

If you want to parse a transaction input then you need the contract abi and using a library like [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) to read the parameters values of the call.

Comment: You're right, however this time, the output is not as expected :'\fH^\u000f\u0015_!m\u0006ç\u000eø[hCÉ±Â÷À¯gì\u001bVÖT'" . Because accordong to this answer : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11144/how-to-decode-input-data-from-a-transaction/11145#11145 I want to decode transaction data such that it would be readable.

Comment: It does work in the link because it was generated by `toHex` (equivalent to today's `asciiToHex`). It doesn't work in your case because it is a raw function call. As I said you will need the contract ABI and a ABI parser to extract info from the parameters of the call.

Answer (score 2):

Like Ismael mention, you have to use `hexToAscii` with web3@^1.0

But looks like you are using it on the `transaction.hash` and not the `transaction.input`

EDIT: example:

Submit transaction:

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const web3 = require('web3');
const data = web3.utils.toHex('Hello world!');
const rawTx = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(gasCost),
    to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    value: '0x00',
    data,
};
const privateKeyWithoutZero = privateKey.startsWith('0x') ? privateKey.slice(2, privateKey.length) : privateKey;
const privateKeyBuffer = new Buffer(privateKeyWithoutZero, 'hex');
const transaction = new Tx(rawTx);
transaction.sign(privateKeyBuffer);

const serializedTx = transaction.serialize();

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
    .on('transactionHash', (txHash) => {
        console.log('Transaction hash', txHash);
})
    .on('receipt', (receipt) => {
        console.log('Transaction sent with sucess. debug:', receipt);
});
```

Then, getTransaction:

```
web3.eth.getTransaction('<TRANSACTION-HASH>')
        .then((transaction) => {
          const inputData = Web3.utils.hexToAscii(transaction.input);
          console.log(inputData); // Hello world!
        });
```

Comment: could u mention an example for transaction.input ? I mean using web3.utils.hexToAscii. Thanks.

Comment: Example added above

Comment: Thank you. Now it's readable. I'm going to install an abi parser like this : https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi to decode the tx data.

Comment: Depends of what is your goal, but if you just want to read the input data, you don't need to use ethereum-abi, I updated my example with a simple working script

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I intend to get Tx data using HTML and JavaScript. I created a github repository here : https://github.com/s1241/GUI-for-Smart-Contract its smart contract tested successfully, however html and javascript is not complete. Are you interested in having a look its HTML file ?

Comment: You just have to implement what I sent you above :) After looks like you don't want to use the transaction.input but a smart contract in your case...