# Monitoring Pending Transactions

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

How would I go about monitoring pending transactions in real-time? Would I be able to monitor only one function?

I have a full node running and have a nodejs (express server) that I want to have this info available to.

I am guessing that a websocket would be the way to go, in which case what would I be listening for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can create a stream of pending transactions using [`web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions' [, callback]);`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-pendingtransactions), which currently returns a transaction hash.
2. You can turn into the actual transaction object using [`web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash [, callback])`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction), which will return a transaction object.
3. You can then filter the returned object by `to` and `input` to find only the transactions that are being sent to a specific contract address and are calling a specific function in that contract.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up coming to the same conclusion myself. It would be nice if pendingTransactions subscription return the full object as per the documentation ;)

Comment: in the input field - what exactly am I looking for? Each transaction is different it seems.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11144/how-to-decode-input-data-from-a-transaction?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: getTransaction() doesn't work with pending transactions unfortunatly. I tried with 4 different versions of Web3.

Comment: @PhilipRego, Were you able to resolve this issue? How to get the pending transaction details using transaction Hash?

Comment: I don't remember but maybe see if ethers.js has it https://docs.ethers.io/v5/

Comment: Not all web3 providers support streaming mempool transactions, if nothing shows up, check your provider

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the show, but to resolve the getTransaction you need to create a buffer, wait till it gets a few confirmations that way the data is more available.

I would suggest creating a batch call, adding them all then rotate through the batch call for the ones you need.