# web3 subscribe to pendingTransactions for a given contract?

Tags: web3js

Is it possible to only subscribe to a specific contract for pendingtransactions using web3.eth.subscribe?
The docs dont show any parameters besides a callback function, so the result shows all pending transactions not just for a contract address like LINK for example.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. use `web3.eth.subscribe` in order to get the list of tx hashes,
2. feed the transaction hash to `web3.eth.getTransaction` to get the transaction object,
3. inspect the resulting object via the `to` and `input` fields, which can be used to filter the specific contract & function.

More details here > https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/49431/89782