# Checking transactions in ganache-cli

Tags: contract-development, transactions, ganache, truffle-migration, ganache-cli

Is there a command to enter into the terminal to check past transactions on the locally deployed ganache-cli blockchain? With [ganache gui](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache) one gets the transactions button. Is there some similar functionality for ganache-cli or does one have to scroll?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [truffle console](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/truffle-commands#console) and [web3-eth API](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html):

```bash
# connect to 'development' network
truffle console
```

---

Get log of the latest transaction:

```bash
truffle(development)> await web3.eth.getPastLogs({})
[
  {
    logIndex: 0,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    transactionHash: '0x8d550f02c2ad9ce0770100ea35fddcb4239605338904999bac0b44ab98d47469',
    blockHash: '0x51cfc9b9fb563729ea9791258d172e2d7e15526fa39df3cc8002d8c1e124b023',
    blockNumber: 14,
    address: '0xc8474d35f43c485A193f4619AD5dfc13E6Ef7670',
    data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    topics: [
      '0x6c0fa476682fe2e95bf3de06aae1b1660cd12883277ff64b03496b5e1a7d08dd',
      '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006047e03d',
      '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006047e040',
      '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006047e041'
    ],
    type: 'mined',
    id: 'log_320edfe0'
  }
]
```

---

Get info about the n-th transaction in n-th block:

```bash
# get info about the first transaction on the 14th block

truffle(development)> await web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(14, 0)
{
  hash: '0x8d550f02c2ad9ce0770100ea35fddcb4239605338904999bac0b44ab98d47469',
  nonce: 7,
  blockHash: '0x51cfc9b9fb563729ea9791258d172e2d7e15526fa39df3cc8002d8c1e124b023',
  blockNumber: 14,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  from: '0xc7815B5AA79E6A215131D633f40379459298D892',
  to: '0xc8474d35f43c485A193f4619AD5dfc13E6Ef7670',
  value: '0',
  gas: 6721975,
  gasPrice: '20000000000',
  input: '0xfed8d203000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e636f6e74726f6c206e756d62657200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000087472616365206964000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e696e766f696365206e756d626572000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  v: '0x26',
  r: '0xe3ee9a1bfca535a673618ed5fcac24ecf3f77d0aab04e6eaacc404d0f231b57f',
  s: '0x15bcb052913f4de6f9457bf9f1ff23ba35a33d11b777c41a74911bbdcc5b964b'
}

# take transaction-hash to get its receipt

truffle(development)> await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x8d550f02c2ad9ce0770100ea35fddcb4239605338904999bac0b44ab98d47469')
{
  transactionHash: '0x8d550f02c2ad9ce0770100ea35fddcb4239605338904999bac0b44ab98d47469',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0x51cfc9b9fb563729ea9791258d172e2d7e15526fa39df3cc8002d8c1e124b023',
  blockNumber: 14,
  from: '0xc7815b5aa79e6a215131d633f40379459298d892',
  to: '0xc8474d35f43c485a193f4619ad5dfc13e6ef7670',
  gasUsed: '0x21db2',
  cumulativeGasUsed: 138674,
  contractAddress: null,
  logs: [
    {
      logIndex: 0,
      transactionIndex: 0,
      transactionHash: '0x8d550f02c2ad9ce0770100ea35fddcb4239605338904999bac0b44ab98d47469',
      blockHash: '0x51cfc9b9fb563729ea9791258d172e2d7e15526fa39df3cc8002d8c1e124b023',
      blockNumber: 14,
      address: '0xc8474d35f43c485A193f4619AD5dfc13E6Ef7670',
      data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      topics: [Array],
      type: 'mined',
      id: 'log_320edfe0'
    }
  ],
  status: true,
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000400000000000000000000000800000000800800000000000004000000000000200000000000400000000000000000000000000000000004020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000'
}
```

---

To decode *TX data* follow this answer [How to decode input data from a transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/94442/67038).