# automate smart contract interaction done manually with metamask using web3.js/ethers.js/

Tags: web3js, etherscan, ethers.js

If I have done a transaction with a smart contract manually with metamask, how can I repeat that progress with a script written in web3.js/ethers.js so I can automate it?

If I am not wrong, I need to get the transaction details from the log? Can I do this with etherscan/bscscan?

Take [this](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x5723c68a343d1405bd0aacf57c546e4acc2d5607be2bf8af61b451d0acbfae16#eventlog) bsc transactions as an example.

Comment: To call a contract you only need the address and the contract abi. The parameters should be the same used in remix.

Comment: I got the idea on how to call a contract. I can get the abi from etherscan/bscscan. The problem is how can I know which function to call and what parameters should I send? Take the example give above, do I just call  swapExactETHForTokens with the parameters give in the input data field ?

Comment: Or precisely, given a txhash, how can I get the transaction details and so I can repeat the transaction using a script?

Comment: You have to decode the *InputData* field on the transaction. To do that take a look at this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/82318.